# Implementing an exit function on my C shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, operating-system, system-calls

I have been trying to implement an exit command on my C shell. I have tried the fork-exec method since it's a system call.
When I run the program, it prompts for the stdin input and when I type in "exit" it returns a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ARGVMAX 100
#define LINESIZE 1024
#define EXITCMD "exit"

//makeargv - builds an argv vector from words in a string

int makeargv(char *s, char *argv[ARGVMAX]) {
    int ntokens = 0;

    if (s == NULL || argv == NULL || ARGVMAX == 0)
        return -1;
    argv[ntokens] = strtok(s, " \t\n");
    while ((argv[ntokens] != NULL) && (ntokens < ARGVMAX)) {
        ntokens++;
        argv[ntokens] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
    argv[ntokens] = NULL; // it must terminate with NULL
    return ntokens;
}

void prompt() {
    printf("sish> ");
    fflush(stdout); //writes the prompt
}

/******  MAIN  ******/
int main() {
    char line[LINESIZE];
    int wstatus;

    while (1) {
        prompt();
        if (fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin) == NULL)
            break;
    // TODO:
        if(fgets(line, LINESIZE, strcmp(stdin, EXITCMD )) == 0)
            return 0;

        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        if (fork() == 0) exit(execvp(line[0], line));
            {
                signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
            }

        wait(&wstatus);
        if(WIFEXITED(wstatus))
            printf("<%d>", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you suppose that `strcmp(stdin, EXITCMD)` does?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and start using a debugger to debug C code, such as `gdb`.  It's really the only viable solution for debugging segmentation faults, other than hoping you or somebody on SO "just sees" the error in the code.

Comment: Compares the input string with the pre defined string “exit” ?

Comment: @VectorSpectra `stdin` is not a string. `line` is a string. Why are you using `strcmp()` as an argument to `fgets()`?

Comment: Call `fgets()` to read a line. Split it into an array of words. Use `strcmp()` to compare the first word with `exit`.

Comment: The second argument to `execvp()` needs to be an array of strings. `line` is a single string, not an array.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I’ll try that now

Comment: `fgets(line, LINESIZE, strcmp(stdin, EXITCMD )` ?? The third argument should be a FILE *.  Surely your compiler warns you about this.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing and cleaning the code, I was finally able to implement the exit command.

Here goes the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define ARGVMAX 100
#define LINESIZE 1024
#define EXITCMD "exit"


//makeargv - build an argv vector from words in a string

int makeargv(char *s, char *argv[ARGVMAX]) {
    int ntokens = 0;

    if (s == NULL || argv == NULL || ARGVMAX == 0)
        return -1;
    argv[ntokens] = strtok(s, " \t\n");
    while ((argv[ntokens] != NULL) && (ntokens < ARGVMAX)) {
        ntokens++;
        argv[ntokens] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
    argv[ntokens] = NULL; // it must terminate with NULL
    return ntokens;
}






void prompt() {
    printf("C Shell >> ");
    fflush(stdout); //writes the prompt
}

/******  MAIN  ******/
int main() {
    char line[LINESIZE];                            


    while (1) {                                     
        prompt();                                   
        if (fgets(line, LINESIZE, stdin) == NULL)   
            break;                                  
    // TODO:
        char *p = strchr(line, '\n');           
        
        if (p)                                      
            *p = 0;                                 
        if(strcmp(line, "exit") == 0)               
            break;                                  

        char *args[] = {line, (char*) 0};
        
        int pid = fork();                           

        if (pid == 0){                               
                execvp(line, args);                 
                perror("Command Error!");           
                exit(1);                            
        } else {                                    
            wait(NULL);                             
        }

        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```